# How to force Python to print when called?

Tags: python

My class includes a call to load data and to train a (deep learning) model; in-between, I have `print` statements for logging purposes:

`get_data() -> print() -> train() -> print()`

`Fitting set 5... (Loss,Acc) = (0.512,0.921)`

`Fitting set` is printed after `get_data()`, and `Loss,Acc` after `train()` - *however*, adding an additional `print` statement within `get_data()`, as below, modifies the output log as follows:

```python
def get_data():
    t0=time()
    data = load_data(path)
    print(time()-t0,'sec')
    return data
```

`Fitting set 5... (Loss,Acc) = (0.512,0.921) 2.486 sec`

The time log is printed *after* `train()`, despite being called *before*. Further, the time log is printed *immediately* after the `Loss,Acc` log, rather than in '2.etc' secs - so it isn't a call order issue.

---

How do I force Python to `print` when it's asked to, rather than later?

Comment: find how to deal with output buffering (some tricks could be applied)

Comment: Python does print when it's asked to. If the output's in the wrong order, it means that you're either using multithreading (so that multiple threads attempt to write to the same terminal), or it's indeed a call order issue.

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like? It's hard to give a useful answer without a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports for more information).

Comment: Does it actually print all those in the same line, or did you just format it in this way?

Comment: @tobias_k It does, via `end=''`

Comment: @ForceBru Unless default Keras uses multithreading, I don't - and no, it isn't a call order issue

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, if `flush` seems to help, but _randomly_, as you say in your other comment, it may be an indicator of usage of threads or processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what works for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/10133797) - pasting:

> You can replace sys.stdout with
>   some other stream like wrapper which
>   does a flush after every call:
>
> ```
> class Unbuffered(object):
>    def __init__(self, stream):
>        self.stream = stream
>    def write(self, data):
>        self.stream.write(data)
>        self.stream.flush()
>    def writelines(self, datas):
>        self.stream.writelines(datas)
>        self.stream.flush()
>    def __getattr__(self, attr):
>        return getattr(self.stream, attr)
>
> import sys
> sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
> print('Hello')
> ```

*Note*: I suggest against marking this question as a duplicate, since I could *not* find an answer to my question with *my* search words (I didn't know what "output buffering" is, which may apply to others)

Answer (score 0):

`print` has a `flush` parameter that when set to true force the flushing.

[`https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: This works _some_ of the time, and partially at that; time log is delayed by _under_ 2 secs. Most of the time the original behavior persists.